# bxslider pager active state does not change after clicking another pager

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using [jQuery bsSlider](http://bxslider.com/) for my slider. The slideshow starts automatically after the page load. The problem is, after starting slideshow, if I click on a pager/dot, that pager/dot remain active for sometime after coming of next slider or previous slider too!

For example, Imagine, there are three sliders. At first, **1st slider** is visible, so **1st dot** is active, if I click **2nd dot**, **2nd slider** will come and **2nd dot** will become active. But, from there, when **3rd slide** are coming automatically, both of ***2nd and 3rd dot*** remaining active! I hope, you can imagine the issue by seeing the screenshot:

[image: bxSlider dot active issue]

js code:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
```

How to fix it?

[Fiddle Work](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/ku39cpdx/4/)

Comment: This happened only when I clicked on either of the dots and hence slider had two events that is one- fired by `auto` and other  by `click`. If I don't click the nav dots, slider works properly

Answer (score 1):

You have to comment this line in the css file:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active
/* .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus */ {
background: #000;
}
```

Comment: I solved it like this way: .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {background-color: #ccc;} 
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active:focus {
  background-color: #000;
}
https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/ku39cpdx/14/

Answer (score 0):

this problem is css style issue in "jquery.bxslider.css".
in css code, you may delete or comment 1 line code

and add callback function your javascript code

here is sample code

[jquery.bxslider.css]

```
/*.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,*/ //<<< remove css or comment
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
/* background: #000; */
background: url(images/custom_pager.png) no-repeat 0 -20px;
```

[your bxslider initialization in javascript code]

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    /* options */
    //...
    //...
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        $(".bx-pager-item a").eq(oldIndex).removeClass("active");
        $(".bx-pager-item a").eq(newIndex).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

you can view that bxslider's option

> in http://bxslider.com/options